# How to use read-host variable in -To argument of send-mailmessage

Tags: powershell

I have written a script that collects logs from several servers then zips them up and sends them via email. As the recipients of these emails can be different depending on the situation I chose to use user input rather than hard-code the email addresses. This is what I have:

```
$to = '"' + (read-host -prompt "Send to") + '"'
do {
Write-host "Add another recipient?"
$choice = read-host -prompt "[y/n]"
switch ($choice) {
'y'{
$add = ',"' + (read-host -prompt "Send to") + '"'
$to = -Join ($to, $add)
}
}
}
until ($choice -eq 'n')
$issuenum = read-host -prompt "Issue Number (enter if none)"
$title = read-host -prompt "Email Title"
$body = read-host -prompt "Message"
Send-MailMessage -To $to -From "test@testemail.com" -SMTPServer smtpserver.com -Subject "[$issuenum] $title" -body $body -attachments $attachments
}
```

However, when running the script I get the following error:

```
Send-MailMessage : An invalid character was found in the mail header: '"'.
At C:\PATH\SCRIPT.ps1:431 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage -To $to -From "test@testemail.com" -SMTPServer  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [Send-MailMessage], FormatException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

Send-MailMessage : A recipient must be specified.
At C:\PATH\SCRIPT.ps1:431 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage -To $to -From "test@testemail.com" -SMTPServer  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

When I display the value of my $to variable it outputs what I expect to see: the correct format for the send-mailmessage -to argument.

```
"test1@testemail.com","test2@testemail.com"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need pass to send-mailmessage a string[] array. [string[]]$recipients = "recipient1@tagada.com", "recipient2@tagada.com"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"a","b"` typed into PowerShell is an array of 2 literal strings, containing no quotes an no comma.

`"a","b"` calculated in code is 1 string containing four quotes and a comma.

`Send-MailMessage` is built to work with the former.

Try making `$to` into an array of strings:

```
$to = @(read-host -prompt "Send to")
do {
    Write-host "Add another recipient?"
    $choice = read-host -prompt "[y/n]"
    switch ($choice) {
       'y'{
            $to += (read-host -prompt "Send to")
        }
    }
}
until ($choice -eq 'n')
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
$to = '"' + (read-host -prompt "Send to") + '"'
```

You are adding *literal* double quotes `"` inside the string.

```
$to = read-host -prompt "Send to"
```

That's all you need.

When you use a quoted string in your code, the quotes tell the *parser* that it's a string; they are not part of the content.

So when specifying a parameter with a literal, you may need quotes (again for the *parser*):

```
-To 'Some@address.com'
```

But when you use a variable, the variable should not contain those quotes.